# Angular Material Table Text Filtering - rxjs - Merging http get results with a filter Subject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I'm trying to apply the sample of [Angular Material Text Filtering](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) using the data from an http get call.

```
export class MyDtoDataSource extends DataSource<IMyDto> {
      private _filterChange = new BehaviorSubject('');
      public get filter(): string { return this._filterChange.value; }
      public set filter(filter: string) { this._filterChange.next(filter); }

      constructor(private _apiService: ApiService) {
          super()
      }

      connect(): Observable<IMyDto[]> {

          const displayDataChanges = [
              this._apiService.getMyDtos(),
              this._filterChange,
          ];

          return Observable
          .merge(...displayDataChanges)
          .map((dtos: IMyDto[]) => dtos.filter(dto => dto.categories.map(i => i.name).includes(this.filter)));
      }

  disconnect() {
  }
}
```

However, I guess there is an issue with my map as I get the runtime error `dtos.filter is not a function`

Comment: `_filterChange` will emit a `string` and not a `IMyDto[]` so including it in the `merge` will see `string` values merged into the observable stream, effecting the error you are seeing. You most likely want to use [`withLatestFrom`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-withLatestFrom) instead of `merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Tks to [@cartant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6680611/cartant) for point me to the right direction.

```
connect(): Observable<IMyDto[]> { 
    return Observable
      .combineLatest(this._apiService.getMyDtos(), this._filterChange)
      .map(([dtos, filter]) => dtos.filter(dto => dto.categories.map(i => i.name).includes(filter)));
 }
```